# How to get hold of div on mousemove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[JSFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/vinvik88/Ljxpj5bt/)

I am trying to get hold of div with blue lines when I move the mouse pointer within a distance of 20px from the div. I am able to get hold of the div with blue lines only when the mouse pointer is on that div. Basically, selecting a div using the mouser pointer is difficult as the div width is only 1px which cannot be changed.

I am executing the below code but still not able to catch hold of the div which is 20px away from either right or left of the mouse pointer.

Note:The div mentioned above indicated the div with blue lines and not the gray box.

```
//Div positions and their id has been added to map
var hmap = new Map();
hmap.set("hguide1",96);
hmap.set("hguide2",284);
hmap.set("hguide3",520);

var vmap = new Map();
vmap.set("vguide1", 96);
vmap.set("vguide2",384);
vmap.set("vguide3",720);

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
   var mx = e.pageX, my = e.pageY;
   //Catch hold of vertical div's
   for (var [key, value] of vmap) {
     var dist = value - mx;
     if(dist >= -20 && dist <= 20){
       $('.'+key).css({width: '10px', left:});
     } else {
       $('.'+key).css({width: '1px'});
     }
   }
   //Catch hold of horizontal div's
   for (var [key, value] of hmap) {
     var dist = value - my;
     if(dist >= -20 && dist <= 20){
        $('.'+key).css({height: '10px'});
     } else {
        $('.'+key).css({height: '1px'});
     }
   }
});
```

I looking for a way thru which I can catch hold of the div, which is 20px away from either the left or right side of the mouse pointer, and drag it.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS styling to get this result. We set the ::after size to 100% - 20px on either the left or top, depending if it's the horizontal or vertical line. We then set our width or height, depending on if we're adjusting the row or column, to either 100% or the buffer size(40px, because we want 20px on either side of the line).

I realize that sounds a little confusing, so I'll split them up. Here's the vertical:

```
.vguide1,.vguide2,.vguide3 {
  border-left: 1px solid blue;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width:1px;
  height:650px;
}
.vguide1::after,.vguide2::after,.vguide3::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
   cursor: col-resize;


}
```

Horizontal:

```
.hguide1,.hguide2,.hguide3 {
  padding-right: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width:850px;
  height:1px;
  border-top: 1px solid blue;

}
.hguide1::after,.hguide2::after,.hguide3::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
   cursor: row-resize;

}
```

With shading to show the hit box: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljxpj5bt/27/

Without hit box: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljxpj5bt/28/

Comment: Nice! I was thinking of a similar thing!

Comment: I would like to catch hold of the div with blue lines and not the div gray box. I am sorry I did not mention it correctly in the question. will update question.

Comment: @TheGaME Ah, I see. Give me a few minutes and I'll help you out!